# Where to place the robots.txt file with G-WAN?

Tags: robots.txt, g-wan

I want to disallow robots from crawling the `csp` folder and plan to use the following robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /csp
```

So, my question is double:

1. Is the syntax correct for G-WAN?
2. With G-WAN, where should I place this file?

Answer (score 0):

The [well-documented](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) robots.txt file should be placed in the /www G-WAN fodler - if you want to use this feature. `robots.txt` is a hint for robots, many of them do not respect your will (so it's much safer to define file-system permissions or use an `index.html` file in the folders that you don't want to be browsed).

The `/csp` directory cannot be crawled by any HTTP client (including robots). Only the `/www` directory can.

This separation has worked pretty well in terms of simplicity, design and security so far, avoiding the pitfall of deciding what is executable and what is the presentation layer.

Comment: Is there anyway to configure G-wan to run purely as a static content server or purely a dynamic content server? I imagine that would eliminate the query character (?) without any url rewriting cost. Most servers in production offload static contents to a CDN anyway.

Comment: To have a static server, erase the /csp and /handlers folders. To have a dynamic server, put nothing in the /www folder. If no G-WAN script matches a request then a STATIC file is searched and the request can then bear a '?' query character.